# "No extensions found" when running Visual Studio Code from source

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I try to install any extension in Visual Studio Code (i.e., by pressing `Ctrl+P` and then running `ext install RustyCode`), I get a message that `No extensions found`.

However, this only happens when I run VS Code directly from source repository. I.e., after:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode.git
cd vscode
git checkout 1.0.0
scripts/code.sh
```

But, if I run VS Code from [official builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads), then I'm able to install extensions.

So, how can I enable downloading and installing extensions from Visual Studio Marketplace when I run VS Code directly from source repository? (Is Visual Studio Marketplace integration bundled separately in official builds?)

I'm on Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding following to `product.json`:

```
"extensionsGallery": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
    "cacheUrl": "https://vscode.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/index",
    "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items"
}
```

*(This is can also be fixed by copying `product.json` from an official build (in the [.zip archvie](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads), `product.json` is under `resources/app`) which contains above lines).*

More information: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1557

Comment: Thank you for this

Comment: Where I should add this `product.json`? On `./build/electron/resources/app`?

Comment: There is already a `product.json` in the root directory of the repository. This goes into that.

Comment: My `product.json` contains these lines, yet not working :(

Comment: There may be a server down somewhere... I've tried on two different computers to search extensions... "No extensions found."

Comment: Just confirmed per [marketplace.visualstudio.com](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) that "Sorry! Our services aren't available right now. We're working to restore all services as quickly as possible. Please check back soon."

If someone encounters this question in the future, check website first if services are available... Will save you time from configuring files / reinstalling software.

Comment: Is it possible to configure the extension repository in a pre-built VSCode OSS?

Comment: On linux look for `/usr/lib/code/product.json`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `code-marketplace` extension in `AUR` to add microsoft marketplace registery in code OSS. This extension will installs a pacman hook that patches the file on every package update.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed, make sure to run `pacman -S code` to let the hook get called if you're not going to update your whole system.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do the same for archlinux, have a look here => https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Visual_Studio_Code , you have various possible options to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For Arch linux you could access the `product.json` file under this path - `/usr/lib/code/product.json`.
Just edit on the file the `extensionsGallery` with the following-

```
"extensionsGallery": {
     "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
     "cacheUrl": "https://vscode.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/index",
     "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items"
}
```

like @Vikrant Chaudhary said.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer from @Vikrant Chaudhary. If anyone wanted to do the same thing on Windows, the path to product.json is here:

Windows path for VSCodium: `C:\Program Files\VSCodium\resources\app\product.json`