# Using extensions in compiled VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I compiled VSCode on mac and was able to run the application but noticed that extensions don't work. 
Navigating to the extensions pane shows - 'No extensions found.'

So I did a grep on the source code for 'marketplace' and found - "build/lib/extensions.js:        base: 'https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery',

I assumed that's the URL for the marketplace and tried doing a curl on it to verify if the API sends back a list of available extensions. All I got back was a 404.

So, if I want to get extensions to work on my compiled version, do I have to change the URL?
How to I get extensions to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No extensions found" when running Visual Studio Code from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143536/no-extensions-found-when-running-visual-studio-code-from-source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See ["No extensions found" when running Visual Studio Code from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143536/no-extensions-found-when-running-visual-studio-code-from-source)

You need to open the file https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/product.json on your fork and append the key:

```
"extensionsGallery": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
    "cacheUrl": "https://vscode.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/index",
    "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items"
}
```

See also the questions:

1. [How do I enable extensions in the extensions dir in OSS Dev mode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23831)
2. [Can I put the extensionsGallery on my vscode fork?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31168)

Comment: This answer's reference has changed and `"extensionsGallery"` is removed from `product.json` in the mentioned git repository. However it's still valid.

Answer (score 12):

It's not clear where the `product.json` file is ...

If you are using `VSCodium` on Mac the `product.json` file is located at: 
`/Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app`

Edit the file using VSCodium:

```
code /Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/product.json
```

If you search for "extensionsGallery" you should see:

[image: vscodium-default-extensionsGallery]

Replace:

```
  "extensionsGallery": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://open-vsx.org/vscode/gallery",
    "itemUrl": "https://open-vsx.org/vscode/item"
  },
```

With:

```
"extensionsGallery": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
    "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items"
},
```

So you now have this:

[image: vscodium-updated-extensionsGallery]

After *restarting* VSCodium, if we open the Extensions Marketplace:
[image: vscodium-open-extensions-marketplace]

If you search for your favourite extension or programming language, you will see *all* of them:
[image: vscodium-full-extention-marketplace]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What would be the path for Linux?

Comment: @DanielDiaz This is the PATH in Ubuntu: `/usr/share/codium/resources/app/product.json`

you can read more in:
https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/blob/master/DOCS.md#extensions-marketplace

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve the issue for archlinux, have a look here => https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Visual_Studio_Code , you have various possible options to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Vscode open source versions (Code -OSS, Vscodium) doesn't use Microsoft extensions gallery by default. Therefore, some extensions will not show up in the extensions tab and the `ext` command won't work

As @nelsonic mentioned the correct way to fix this in Mac is to edit the `/Applications/VSCodium.app/Contents/Resources/app/product.json` file.

In Linux, this is quite different. If you are using `Code -OSS` you edit the following file: `/usr/lib/code/product.json`.

If you use `VsCodium` you edit: `/usr/lib/codium/product.json`

You must change the key `extensionsGallery` from:

```json
    "extensionsGallery": {
        "serviceUrl": "https://open-vsx.org/vscode/gallery",
        "itemUrl": "https://open-vsx.org/vscode/item"
    },
```

[image: Before]

To:

```json
"extensionsGallery": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
    "cacheUrl": "https://vscode.blob.core.windows.net/gallery/index",
    "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items"
}
```

[image: After]