# Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu shows "No extensions found"

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I tried most of the stuff I could find online.

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on my machine and I installed Visual Studio Code, but the Extension Tab seems not to be functional at all - whatever I type the  `"No Extensions found."` text gets outputted.

I tried ["No extensions found" when running Visual Studio Code from source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37143536/7091515) with no success, also I tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code, either from .deb or from terminal, nothing seems to work. I doubt that it is OS fault considering that I did a fresh install.

Any help?

EDIT: I Just woke up a couple of my friends, they all have the same issue. Seems server related. Sorry for the incovenience, someone should close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice to meet you.

I'm sure your problem is related with VSCode downtime :)

[image]

More information about this: https://twitter.com/code/status/1037215136812032001