# Unable to install vscode live share on manjaro linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

I'm unable to install live share on manjaro linux. I am searching the extension but I'm unable to find it. I also trie `ext install MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack` via `Ctrl+p` but no luck. I don't understand why it's not showing up.

Search Result for the extension.
[image: extension search]

My vscode version.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a problem with the OSS build. I used the official binary build for Linux and it worked.

Comment: Using closed binary should not be an accepted reply. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71659052/2480481 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67408856/2480481. Usually doing this takes much more time than findind the correct answer. Regards.